# Send email alert if Jenkins agent is Offline - script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-agent

I have Jenkins agent nodes and need to set email alert if some of the nodes are down.
Manage to get the list of offline nodes, but struggling with email part.

```
int exitcode = 0
for (slave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
    if (slave.getComputer().isOffline().toString() == "true"){
        println('Slave ' + slave.name + " is offline!");
        exitcode++;
    }
}

if (exitcode > 0){
    println("We have a Slave down, failing the build!");
    return 1;
    send_email_notification()
}

def send_email_notification(String body) {
    emailext body: "$body",
            to: "username@domainname.com",
            subject: "Offline Slave",
            presendScript : "msg.addHeader('X-Priority', '1 (Highest)')"
}
```

No Errors inside of Jenkins Script Console:

Result
Slave NODE01 is offline!
We have a Slave down, failing the build!
Result: 1

But I am not receiving an email.

Comment: Is this problem got fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Do you have any errors?</strike> Are you able to receive any emails? Is the email server configured in https://{JENKINS_URL}/configure?

What happens if you run this:

```
emailext body: "Testing",
            to: "username@domainname.com",
            subject: "Offline Slave",
            presendScript : "msg.addHeader('X-Priority', '1 (Highest)')"
```

It looks to me like you aren't passing a body to the send_email_notification() call.  Try this:

```
def send_email_notification(String body) {
    emailext body: "${body}",
            to: "username@domainname.com",
            subject: "Offline Slave",
            presendScript : "msg.addHeader('X-Priority', '1 (Highest)')"
}
for (slave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
    if (slave.getComputer().isOffline().toString() == "true"){
        msg = "Slave " + slave.name + " is offline!";
        send_email_notification("${msg}")
    }
}
```